# how to select where like 'x%' excluding a letter?

Tags: mysql, select

```
select * from mytable where col like 'xy.%';
```

How to exclude the results that contain the letter 'y' after the '.'?

**example:**
Show the result 'xy.abc' *but*
exclude the result 'xy.aybc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select * From mytable Where col like 'xy.%' AND col NOT like 'xy.%y%';
```

Comment: I still want it to start with 'x'

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I have changed it as per your question changes